# Why LinkedBlockingQueue#poll() may hang up?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java

This is my code:

```
// in constructor
BlockingQueue<Node> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Node>();
// later in another thread
Node node = queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Usually it works, but sometimes, under some circumstances (still don't know when and why) `poll()` method doesn't return `NULL` but keeps its thread in `WAITING` state forever. Why and how this could happen?

I tried `ArrayBlockingQueue` - the same effect. I'm using OpenJDK on Mac OS:

```
java version "1.7.0_05" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

The same code works just fine with Oracle Java 1.6 on Mac OS. This is where the threads are stuck:

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:894)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1221)
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:340)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:462)
```

What's interesting is that when I `interrupt()` this thread and try to `poll()` again I reach the same situation immediately.

Comment: This is most likely a bug, I would try the latest version of OpenJDK 7 or Oracle Java 7 update 7. As this uses a system call, I would also make sure you have a supported version of the OS.

Comment: Can you show a stacktrace of the thread in `WAITING` state?

Comment: Can you write a reproduce able simple program.

Comment: I updated my question with more details

Comment: Is the `queue` marked as final or is it replaced every so often?  I worry about the "in constructor" comment.

Comment: Of course it's final :) The problem is that `LinkedBlockingQueue` locks itself for reading using `ReentrantLock` and never gets unlocked, for some reason, sometimes...

Comment: I agree with @Peter.  This is smelling like a JDK bug.  Have you trolled the Oracle bug lists?

Comment: I just did: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk7-dev/2012-September/002303.html

Comment: You don't really give enough information to solve this problem. When dealing with multi-threaded code, showing the setup and then hand-waving: "Later in another thread" isn't enough. Can you update your question with a simple program (both queue creation and access) which can reproduce the problem, at least relatively reliably?

Comment: This bug does seem fixed in JDK7: see this [bug report](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6871697). Did you really try to reproduce your bug in JDK7?

Comment: The stack trace doesn't show which LinkedBlockQueue is being polled, are you sure it's your own?  Some classes like Executor implementations uses blocking queues internally.

Comment: So, did a JVM update solve your issue?

Comment: is this resolved? i see the pointers http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6871697
http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do;jsessionid=e32efec12fe4e451c185b227194b?bug_id=6815766
I run into this with ArrayBlockingQueue and not just with poll(), a take() and also put(). Blocks the entire queue and holds my processor queue.

Answer (score 3):

That's a [nasty] issue that has been solved in the early versions of Java 7. If you migrate to the newer JVM you won't have that problem (it appears the fix has not been back-ported to Java 6).

See [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6871697) and [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=e32efec12fe4e451c185b227194b?bug_id=6815766).